# How to see the supported Char Set in UNIX JVM

Tags: unix, websphere

I need to use IBM charset cp1388 on my UNIX JVM. 
How do I see if my JVM supports this charset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class CharsetList {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        for (String key: Charset.availableCharsets().keySet()) {
           System.out.println(key);
        }
    }
}
```